# What is the English translation of "Bemerfungen"?

Tags: german-to-english, blackletter

I've tried google and bing translate as well as asking my uncle (a native German speaker, born in Germany). None have a translation, my uncle's response was

> the word Bemerfungen has me stumped. It is perhaps an old german word no longer used today

So what does *Bemerfungen* mean? The specific context for the word is a column heading on an old church record. The column I need translated is the last column in the image.

[image: Image of document]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You misread a *k* for an *f*. The correct spelling is Bemer**k**ungen: *Nachträgliche Bemerkungen* = subsequent remarks.

It is written correctly in the form. The Fraktur glyph for the letter *k* looks similar to a modern *f:*

[image]

See: [Fraktur in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur)

Comment: The image has an _f_ in _Taufpathen_ (modern spelling: _Taufpaten_), for comparison. Unlike _f_, the _k_ has no descender, and they look different at the top.

Comment: Here is a good chart showing individual letters: http://www.library.yale.edu/cataloging/music/fraktur.htm